# Service Bus throws System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 50002 when publishing message

Tags: messaging, servicebus

We have onsite (Windows) service bus instance which has developed a fault.

When publishing a message we get a "`System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 50002`" exception. We do not believe this is code related as it started happening on a branch of code which had been working. The full stack trace of the exception is provided at the end of this question.

I've run the following PowerShell commands on the box and they all appear to indicate service bus is running correctly.

```
get-sbFarmStatus
get-sbFarm
get-SBMessageContainer
get-sbclientconfiguration
```

Service bus explorer manages to access the queues and topics but is unable to read any of the messages

The output it as follows.

```
<17:59:37> The application is now connected to the sb://foo.com:9355/ServiceBusDefaultNamespace service bus namespace.
<17:59:37> MessagingFactory successfully created
<17:59:37> The queue batchrulesqueue has been succesfully retrieved.
<17:59:37> The queue emailqueue has been succesfully retrieved.
<17:59:37> The queue recordsubmittedqueue has been succesfully retrieved.
<17:59:37> The topic iceeventstopic has been succesfully retrieved.
<18:00:12> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. The server was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. If the problem persists, please contact your Service Bus administrator and provide the tracking id..TrackingId:d3433f00-708d-4494-b3de-aecadeb42eeb_GTPR-MC01,TimeStamp:19/04/2017 17:00:12. Method <GetSubscriptions>b__63: retry 1 of 10...
<18:05:24> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. The server was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. If the problem persists, please contact your Service Bus administrator and provide the tracking id..TrackingId:c64a9847-67f9-4c44-b241-7d43526bbe6c_GTPR-MC01,TimeStamp:19/04/2017 17:05:24. Method <GetSubscriptions>b__63: retry 10 of 10.
<18:06:01> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. The server was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. If the problem persists, please contact your Service Bus administrator and provide the tracking id..TrackingId:f1cb6f00-6753-4bde-80d4-a1e22b4fa904_GTPR-MC01,TimeStamp:19/04/2017 17:06:00
<18:06:01> InnerException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

When trying to create a queue

```
<15:09:12> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. SubCode=50000. Internal  Server Error.TrackingId:1d6b0877-7533-4ca9-a670-5bbbed247cc5_GTPR-MC01,TimeStamp:20/04/2017 14:09:12. Method <CreateQueue>b__7c: retry 1 of 10...
<15:09:14> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. SubCode=40901. Another conflicting operation is in progress..TrackingId:5137721b-0da9-4b33-860b-b0fb1822d802_GTPR-MC01,TimeStamp:20/04/2017 14:09:14. Method <CreateQueue>b__7c: retry 10 of 10.
<15:09:14> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. SubCode=40901. Another conflicting operation is in progress..TrackingId:f64591d2-efde-42fb-9cd9-89bb6168e9a0_GTPR-MC01,TimeStamp:20/04/2017 14:09:14
<15:09:14> InnerException: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.
```

When trying to create a topic

```
<15:09:14> InnerException: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.
<15:10:47> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error. SubCode=50000. Internal  Server Error.TrackingId:9ade05de-9eb5-40bb-b33f-7bf4954bde9a_GTPR-MC01,TimeStamp:20/04/2017 14:10:47. Method <CreateTopic>b__90: retry 1 of 10.
<15:10:49> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. SubCode=40901. Another conflicting operation is in progress..TrackingId:dc98a3b4-8515-4dbf-b941-112613450641_GTPR-MC01,TimeStamp:20/04/2017 14:10:49. Method <CreateTopic>b__90: retry 10 of 10.
<15:10:49> InnerException: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.
```

Here is the full stack trace from the client.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingException: 50002: Provider Internal Error.TrackingId:cfda6472-d5d2-4e6b-ad0a-00a745dd0be6_GTPR-MC01_GTPR-MC01,TimeStamp:19/04/2017 09:32:07 ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 50002: Provider Internal Error.TrackingId:cfda6472-d5d2-4e6b-ad0a-00a745dd0be6_GTPR-MC01_GTPR-MC01,TimeStamp:19/04/2017 09:32:07

Server stack trace: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.ThrowIfFaultMessage(Message wcfMessage)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.HandleMessageReceived(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.DuplexRequestBindingElement.DuplexRequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<>c__DisplayClass17.<GetAsyncSteps>b__a(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [2]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.RedirectBindingElement.RedirectContainerChannelFactory`1.RedirectContainerSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.RequestAsyncResult.<GetAsyncSteps>b__4(RequestAsyncResult thisPtr, IAsyncResult r)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [3]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ReconnectBindingElement.ReconnectChannelFactory`1.RequestSessionChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.IteratorAsyncResult`1.StepCallback(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [4]: 
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.OnEndClose(IAsyncResult result)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Sbmp.SbmpMessageSender.OnEndClose(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageClientEntity.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessageClientEntity.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Channels.ServiceBusOutputChannel.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.TypedServiceChannelFactory`1.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnClose(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Close(TimeSpan timeout)
   at Messaging.Infrastructure.Tcp.ChannelFactoryComponents.ChannelFactoryAdapter`1.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Messaging.Infrastructure.Tcp.ChannelFactoryComponents.ChannelFactoryAdapter`1.Dispose()
   at Messaging.Infrastructure.Tcp.Publishers.TprMessagePublisher`1.Publish(IEnumerable`1 messages, QueueType queueType)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MCNotifications.Application.Services.TaskService.Wait(Task task) in e:\Builds\19\Scrum\MCNotifications-R28\Sources\Assemblies\MCNotifications.Application\Services\TaskService.cs:line 16
   at MCNotifications.Application.Services.EmailMessagePublisher.PublishEmailMessage(EmailMessageDto emailMessage) in e:\Builds\19\Scrum\MCNotifications-R28\Sources\Assemblies\MCNotifications.Application\Services\EmailMessagePublisher.cs:line 31
   at MCNotifications.Application.Commands.EmailMessageCommand.ProcessMessage(BrokeredMessageContainer messageContainer) in e:\Builds\19\Scrum\MCNotifications-R28\Sources\Assemblies\MCNotifications.Application\Commands\EmailMessageCommand.cs:line 42
   at MCNotifications.Application.Decorators.CompleteMessageDecorator.ProcessMessage(BrokeredMessageContainer messageContainer) in e:\Builds\19\Scrum\MCNotifications-R28\Sources\Assemblies\MCNotifications.Application\Decorators\CompleteMessageDecorator.cs:line 30
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.MessagingException: 50002: Provider Internal Error.TrackingId:cfda6472-d5d2-4e6b-ad0a-00a745dd0be6_GTPR-MC01_GTPR-MC01,TimeStamp:19/04/2017 09:32:07 ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 50002: Provider Internal Error.TrackingId:cfda6472-d5d2-4e6b-ad0a-00a745dd0be6_GTPR-MC01_GTPR-MC01,TimeStamp:19/04/2017 09:32:07
```

Is there a way of getting more detailed information from ServiceBus to find out what the issue is, run out of ideas and have been stuck on this issue for some time.

Regards

Steve

Answer (score 2):

As is so often the case I fixed my issue shortly after posting this (having spend a couple days pulling my hair out).

As stated in this link, in order to get the all error messages from ServiceBus you need to enable the "Show Analytic and Debug Logs" in the Event Viewer.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193001.aspx

Looking in the Operational section of the Microsoft-ServiceBus folder showed me the exception was being caused by the transaction log of the database being full. When the database had been recreated from a live backup the process to clear out the logs wasn't migrated with it.

[image: Finding the exception]